# php class and variables

Tags: php, class, variables, static, extend

Say I have a class

```
class person {
    public static function get_pk(){
        return self::$primary_key;
    }
}
```

and an extended class

```
class user extends person {
    protected $primary_key = 'id';
}
```

and I want to run:

```
echo user::get_pk(); // should echo id
```

Whenever I run this it fails naturally since $primary_key is not a static variable. How do I get it to return the primary key?

Yes, I can change the class structure, function structure and make it non-static, but for all intents and purposes assume the only thing we can change is the content of the static function get_pk

Comment: You will need to declare a variable of the class to access the variable.  It is not available without reference.

Comment: The real question is, why are `$primary_key` and `get_pk()` static in `person`? That doesn't make a whole lot of sense if you ask me.

Comment: @NullUserException It makes sense in the global context of my projects, but obviously when showing just the 'breaking' part it won't make much sense =)

Comment: @Kami What do you mean exactly? Do you mean to instantiate a class within the class and then pull the variable? $class = get_called_class(); $obj = new $class; return $obj->$primary_key; ... Like that? (Although I'd prefer not to create a whole instantiation just for 1 variable =/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can see this done is by declaring the $primary_key variable in the parent class and then assigning a value to it outside of the child class definition scope. (Notice, I've added `abstract` operators to indicate that the classes are static and capitalized the first letters of the class names to follow the convention.)

```
<?

abstract class Person {
    public static $primary_key;
    public static function get_pk() {
        return self::$primary_key;
    }
}

abstract class User extends Person {
}

User::$primary_key = 'id';
echo User::get_pk();

/* End of file */
```

**UPDATE**

Aram, if you want the $primary_key to stay non-static then the method will need to be non-static as well as "the pseudo-variable $this is not available inside the method declared as static" as per the [Static Keyword manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).

Alternatively you could convert your code to use instantiated class objects:

```
<?

class Person {
    public function get_pk() {
        return $this->primary_key;
    }
}

class User extends Person {
    protected $primary_key = 'id';
}

$user = new User();
echo $user->get_pk();

/* End of file */
```

Comment: This won't work because I want $primary_key to stay non-static

Comment: My point is I want $primary_key to stay non-static and the function get_pk to stay static... That is the issue I am facing. I know I can easily change the static nature of either of those to make it work, but that won't help me with the code or answer the question...

Comment: according to the PHP manual (link above) this is impossible. But I'll be curious to see if you find a work around ;-) Good luck!

Comment: Yay for being impossible! If I find something that works, I'll let you guys know =) Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access non-static properties from `static` methods, since for the properties to be created the class needs to be instantiated. You can introspect the class to get values of its definition though:

```
public static function get_pk() {
    $class = new ReflectionClass(get_called_class());
    $props = $class->getDefaultProperties();
    return $props['primary_key'];
}
```

But really, this is pretty messy and I would not recommend this for production use. Structure your classes properly to be either `static` or not `static`.

Answer (score 0):

Static variables/methods relate to the class i.e. does not require an object to be created. Your `primary_key` variable is created for each object. So the static method is unable to access it because the static method has no notion of a particular object and therefore does not know anything about the `primary_key`. Static methods do not have the variable `$this` (hence `self`) defined.

I guess your best bet is to review [static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) keyword.